# Ruby on Rails - Emoji not saved in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, emoji

I'm working on a Rails app where users can upload photos to their profiles. Every photo has a title, which is supposed to support emoji. Despite changing encoding of the table to *utf8mb4* and modifying *database.yml* when i try to save a photo with emoji in its title MySQL returns an error 'incorrect string value'.

The app is working on Rails 5.0.0.1 with Ruby 2.3.0, MySQL is working on version 5.7.16.

Migration file:

```
class CreateUserPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_photos do |t|
      t.string  :title
      t.string  :filename, null: false
      t.integer :visibility, null: false, default: 0
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        execute "ALTER TABLE `user_photos` CHANGE `title` `title` VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;"
      end

      dir.down do
        execute "ALTER TABLE `user_photos` CHANGE `title` `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  reconnect: false
  database: app_db
  pool: 5
  username: app_user
  password: app_password
  host: localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://blog.metova.com/add-emoji-support-rails-4-mysql-5-5/) can help? Other than encoding, maybe you also have to set charset, among other things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set table's collation to `utf8mb4_bin` instead of `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`:

```
ALTER TABLE user_photos CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

And also change `collation` property value in `database.yml`

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @A.Jasinski no problem :)

Comment: Why is `utf8mb4_bin` better than `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`? In my internet travels I've only seen recommendations to use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Thanks.