# Consequences of modifying mysql encoding from utf8 to utf8mb4 in existing rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I am working on existing rails project with more than 100 tables.

I am adding new table and one of the column should be able to handle emojis.

As suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117279/ruby-on-rails-emoji-not-saved-in-mysql) I have added **encoding: utf8mb4** in database.yml

just doing encoding change, I am able to add emojis.
What will be the consequences on other existing tables.

any better approach that can be followed?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (5.6 and 5.7 _may_ have significant consequences.)

Comment: @Rick I am using 5.7 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_schema, '`.`', table_name,
              '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;')   -- see note
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema',
            'performance_schema', 'sys');
```

Then copy/paste the output into a client tool.

Caveat:  This will convert all VARCHAR/TEXT columns to utf8mb4, even those that you might want to keep as, say, ascii.